# Session Preview Token Expiration

Tags: experience-manager, session

I am trying to increase the expiration time for my session preview tokens, I wonder if it is configurable.

By default it gives you about 3 minutes, but I think it is too short, I would like to increase it to 20 minutes.

Any idea would be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to update the timeout node value in the cd_storage_conf.xml file of your content delivery web-service. This appears to be a keep alive, and not a fixed timeout value.

Timeout value is in milliseconds, and is set to 1 minute below, default is 120000 or 2 minutes if my memory serves me correctly.

```
    <Wrappers>
        <Wrapper Name="SessionWrapper">
             <Timeout>600000</Timeout>
                 <Storage Type="persistence" Id="db-session-webservice" dialect="MSSQL"
                 Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory">
                 <Pool Type="jdbc" Size="5" MonitorInterval="60" 
                 IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120" />
                     <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
                         <Property Name="serverName" Value="DB_NAME" />
                         <Property Name="portNumber" Value="1433" />
                         <Property Name="databaseName" Value="Tridion_Broker_Session_Preview" />
                         <Property Name="user" Value="TridionSessionPreviewUser" />
                         <Property Name="password" Value="Tr1d10n" />
                     </DataSource>
                 </Storage>
        </Wrapper>
    </Wrappers>
```

Comment: Please note that the `<Timeout></Timeout>` element needs to be implemented on the website's `cd_storage_conf.xml`, not the webservice application (if the webservice and website application are separate applications)