# Can we configure Session Preview storage settings?

Tags: experience-manager, session-preview

Possibly related to "[Session Preview Token Expiration](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/1851/46)" but in reverse: **can we configure how long Session Preview keeps session-based pages and component presentations?**

Alternatively, is it "safe" to remove Session Preview pages (e.g. default_0a96e2b2-c5f6-48f0-aab1-32de70a0bd60.aspx) from the file system? I'd like to remove unneeded (dynamic) component presentations as well, if possible.

*The use case is for environments with limited disk space such as training images or VMs.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can configure how long these files remain in your webserver's file system, and it is the same setting.

If you are not seeing these files being removed it means that you forgot to set some cartridges in cd_ambient_conf.xml:

```
<Cartridges>
  <Cartridge File="cd_webservice_preview_cartridge.xml" />
  <Cartridge File="footprint_cartridge_conf.xml" />
</Cartridges>
```

After restarting your files should be removed from the webserver's file system.

PS - Yes, it is safe to delete those files.

Comment: Nice, now I can continue breaking my environment in other ways. :-D